# How to impose generic constraints to the parameters and return values of a function argument of a generic Kotlin function?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to define a Kotlin generic function that takes a lambda as a parameter, but I want to restrict the allowed types of lambdas parameters and return types. How do I do this in Kotlin?

In the following example, I expected the constraint: `where T: Base, V: (T) -> Unit` to mean that `V` can only be functions whose first parameter implements `Base`.

However, I see that the compiler ignores the `T: Base` part of the constraint and will accept any `(Any) -> Unit`.

```kotlin
interface Base

fun <T, V> exampleGenericFunction(func: V) where T: Base, V: (T) -> Unit {
    println("func is $func")
}

class ImplementsBase : Base

class DoesNotImplementBase

fun main() {
    val f1: (ImplementsBase) -> Unit = { }
    exampleGenericFunction(f1)
    
    val f2: (DoesNotImplementBase) -> Unit = { }
    exampleGenericFunction(f2) // expected this to be a compilation error
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is what you want to do? You are doing some very weird things here - forcing function parameter types to be _covariant_, when they are naturally contravariant. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler behaves weirdly too. I don't know if you have realised this, but you have no way of calling `func` in `exampleGenericFunction`. It needs a `T`, and you don't have a way to make one.

Comment: This for sure is a compiler bug

Comment: "Are you sure this is what you want to do?"


In my more complex real world problem I am doing some (perhaps ill-advised) stuff with reflection. A `T` does eventually turn up to be passed to the function and if there is a mistake it's a runtime error. But I am trying to turn these runtime errors into compile time errors if possible.

It's always a bug if the user of this code passes something like: `(DoesntImplementBase) -> Unit`. I thought that this `where` clause would enforce that at compile time. But it seems not to.

Comment: Actually, if you pass `T` to the function then everything starts to work as you expect - it fails at compile time when using `DoesNotImplementBase`, but works fine with `ImplementsBase`. Anyway, I believe this is a bug in the compiler. If we make `T` a reified param then we can even write the code that does not contain any unchecked casts and does not generate warnings, but throws `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: My interface is something like:
`fun <T> register(func: (T) -> Unit) { ... }`
then elsewhere in the code
`fun <T> use_registered_func(instance: T) { ... }`
so I don't pass the `T` until much later so that won't save me.

In any case, thanks all for the comments. This is very helpful. I now understand that my current approach isn't going to work (at least for now). I can live with this being a runtime error for now.

Comment: OK, My project is Kotlin `1.5.21`. In Kotlin `1.3.72` this is a compiler error as expected. Compiler bug seems then to be the problem. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unexpected behavior was caused by a bug in the Kotlin `>=1.4` compiler.
This bug can be tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48935.